# React TypeScript - children of HTML and React Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I have a `PopoverMenu` component in which I would like to access and use the `children` prop. I have seen numerous posts similar to this but not similar enough to help my case.

`children` could be standard HTML or other React components.

Here is the `PopoverMenu` component:

```
export const PopoverMenu = (children) =>
{
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

    if (visible) {
        return (
            <ul ref={ node } className="popover-menu">
                { children }
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

...and here is the component in use...

```
<PopoverMenu>
    <PopoverMenuItem>
      Edit
    </PopoverMenuItem>
    <PopoverMenuItem>
      Delete
    </PopoverMenuItem>
</PopoverMenu>
```

...or alternatively...

```
<PopoverMenu>
    <li>
      <a>Edit</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Delete</a>
    </li>
</PopoverMenu>
```

I have tried a variety of types for `children` but my IDE seems to complain about all of them. These include:

`ReactNode`

`HTMLElement`

`ReactChildren`

What type(s) would give me the desired result and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of Children should be `ReactNode`.

But you need to correct the props destructuring : it should be `({ children })`.

Also, you need to return something from the `else` block. If you want to show nothing, you can `return null`.

Comment: so after updating my code to this `({children}: {children: ReactNode})` when I attempt to use the component I get this from my IDE `'PopoverMenu' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Element | undefined' is not a valid JSX element.`

Comment: https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react seems to be a good collection of React Typings.